# Is there a way I can restructure part of a destructuring assignment?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Let's say I have an array of arrays, like so:

```
var arrs = [
    [1, "foo", "bar", "baz"],
    [2, "bar", "baz", "qux"],
    [3, "baz", "qux", "thud"]
];
```

I want to use ES6's destructuring assignment to get the first element of each array as an individual variable, and repack the rest of the elements as another array. In pseudocode:

```
for (let [first, *rest] of arrs) { // What is the proper way to do *rest?
    console.log(first); // Should be a number
    console.log(rest); // Should be an array of strings
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: `groupBy(x => \`${x.type}-{x.status}\``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what `...` does:

```
for (let [first, ... rest] of arrs) {
```

Comment: Ah, didn't know about this syntax. Does this also work for indexed destructuring assignments? Something like `{ id, ...rest } of { id: 1, some: "foo", other: "bar", properties: "baz" }`?

Comment: @Asad [yes, it works for objects too](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Note the `//ES7` comment on the object example. It'll work if you're using Babel, but it isn't in ES6.

Comment: @loganfsmyth oh yes you're right; I just noticed that as I went back to close that browser tab :)  I admit that I hadn't seen that written out before now, though I recall somebody mentioning it at some point.

Comment: Also (according to the chart on that MDN page) this isn't supported by any environment other than Firefox at the moment (summer 2015).

Comment: @Pointy That's fine, I'm using JSPM and traceur anyway.

Comment: @Pointy isn't that really the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)?

Comment: @royhowie well it's certainly the same token; whether or not this would be considered a use of the spread operator or if it would go by a different name, I can't say. I suppose it's a pretty similar meaning.